# AccessibilityService's onAccessibilityEvent not called if other AccessibilityService is running

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

My app makes use of an AccessibilityService which runs as expected, unless I enable the AccessibilityService of an app called LongShot. My Service keeps active, but onAccessibilityEvent is never called. Disabling LongShot's service solves it.

> To reproduce:

**1. Both services are disabled,**

**2. Enable LongShot's service,**

**3. Enable my service.**

It only happens in this order. I have tested it with other services, namely TalkBack, Switch access and Shh - WhatsApp Incognito; none of them result in the same problem.

It may occur with more AccessibilityServices, so forcing the user to disable other services is not an option.

**Why does this happen and what can I do to prevent it?**

Android 6.0.

> event types:

```
TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED, AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED, AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED;
```